# How Drupal 6 module "Webform Protected Downloads" Configured

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-webform

Hi all I am using Webform Protected Downloads module for Drupal 6. I am facing the problem that when i go to "protected download" tab it gives me the message "You need to attach files to this node before you can configure protected downloads." Where can I attach a file to configure the "Webform Protected Downloads" module?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the default drupal edit page of the given node and upload at least one attachment. Check the private checkbox for every attachment that you want to protect. Then go back to the configuration page for protected downloads. The warning should be gone now.